# How to put x-axis values in order

Tags: python

I have an Excel sheet with some players' heights/weights/ages etc. I'm trying to make a basic graph where I can show an average height/weight ratio and order x-axis from low to high? Sorry I'm just a beginner

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

var = pd.read_excel("C:\Program Files\currentnbaplayerslist.xlsx")
print(var)

x = list(var['Height'])
y = list(var['Weight'])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.scatter(x,y,marker="o",s=100,edgecolors="white",c="green")
plt.title("NBA players' height/weight")
plt.xlabel("Height")
plt.ylabel("Weight")

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

this is the result i get:
[image: this is the result i get]

Comment: share your currentnbaplayerslist.xlsx file. First thing I notice is height is not in a standard format. you have 7' 4 mixed in with float values (I'm assuming cm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your data, I can only make an assumption here. But it looks like you have 2 measurements for height. You need to convert it to be all the same type. So here's a function to convert `7' 4"` into centimetres. Then it should work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import re


def feet_to_cm(x):
    try:
        h_cm = float(x)
        return h_cm
    except:    
        h_ft, h_inch = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', x)]
        h_inch += h_ft * 12
        h_cm = h_inch * 2.54
        return h_cm

data = {'Height':[190.58,198.12,187.96, "7' 4"],
        'Weight':[240.3, 278.25, 180.5, 166]}

#var = pd.read_excel("C:\Program Files\currentnbaplayerslist.xlsx")
var = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(var)

var['Height'] = var.apply(lambda row: feet_to_cm(row['Height']), axis=1)

x = list(var['Height'])
y = list(var['Weight'])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.scatter(x,y,marker="o",s=100,edgecolors="white",c="green")
plt.title("NBA players' height/weight")
plt.xlabel("Height")
plt.ylabel("Weight")

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]